# Help on calculation in Zwanzig, "Nonequilibrium Statistical Mechanics"

Tags: statistical-mechanics, non-equilibrium, textbook-erratum

I'm trying to verify a calculation from Zwanzig's *Nonequilibrium Statistical Mechanics* text from chapter two, deriving the Fokker-Planck Equation from a Langevin Equation, specifically equation (2.41).

Define the Langevin equation,
\begin{equation}\dot{\boldsymbol{a}}=\boldsymbol{v}(\boldsymbol{a})+\boldsymbol{F}(t)\end{equation}
where $\boldsymbol{v}$ is a general function of $\boldsymbol{a}$, and $\boldsymbol{F}$ is a Gaussian, white noise process:
$$\langle\boldsymbol{F}(t)\rangle_{t}=\boldsymbol{0}\\
\langle\boldsymbol{F}(t)\boldsymbol{F}(s)\rangle_{t}=2\boldsymbol{\mathbf{B}}\delta(t-s)$$
Seeking a pdf $f(\boldsymbol{a},t)$ for $\boldsymbol{a}$, we invoke a conservation law over the state space of $\boldsymbol{a}$:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{a}}\cdot\left(f\,\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{a}}{\partial t}\right)$$
Using the Langevin equation for $\boldsymbol{a}$, we have
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{a}}\cdot\left(f(\boldsymbol{a},t)\,\boldsymbol{v}(\boldsymbol{a})+f(\boldsymbol{a},t)\boldsymbol{F}(t)\right)$$
Define an operator $K$ by $$K\,u=\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{a}}\cdot\left(\boldsymbol{v}(\boldsymbol{a})\,u\right)$$
We can rewrite the conservation law,
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=-K\,f-\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{a}}\cdot\left(f(\boldsymbol{a},t)\boldsymbol{F}(t)\right) \tag{1}$$

The noiseless conservation law then admits an operator solution, 
$$f(\boldsymbol{a},t)=e^{-tK}f(\boldsymbol{a},0)$$
With noise, we can write a solution 
$$f(\boldsymbol{a},t)=e^{-tK}f(\boldsymbol{a},0)-\int_0^te^{-(t-s)K}\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{a}}\cdot\left(f(\boldsymbol{a},s)\boldsymbol{F}(s)\right)\,ds \tag{2}$$

What I'm stuck on is how substituting equation (2) into the right-hand side of equation (1) is supposed to beget,
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=-K\,f
-\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{a}}\cdot\left(f(\boldsymbol{a},0)F(t)\right)
+\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{a}}\cdot\left[F(t)\int_0^te^{-(t-s)K}\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{a}}\cdot\left(f(\boldsymbol{a},s)\boldsymbol{F}(s)\right)\,ds\right] \tag{3}$$

Specifically, I can't get the middle term, $\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{a}}\cdot\left(f(\boldsymbol{a},0)F(t)\right)$. My computation always results in, 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=-K\,f
-\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{a}}\cdot\left(e^{-tK}f(\boldsymbol{a},0)F(t)\right)
+\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{a}}\cdot\left[F(t)\int_0^te^{-(t-s)K}\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{a}}\cdot\left(f(\boldsymbol{a},s)\boldsymbol{F}(s)\right)\,ds\right] \tag{4}$$

One must average equation (3) over the noise to derive the Fokker-Planck equation; the *correct* middle term should drop out due to the time independence of the initial conditions and the fact that the noise is mean-zero. However, the middle term I derive can't: the propagator gives time dependence which doesn't guarantee a mean-zero time average.

What am I missing? This should be a simple substitution/verification, but I've done it over 5 times now, and the propagator persists in that middle term under the divergence.

**Edit**: Could the book equation be a typo? And could the middle term on the right hand side of equation (4) still drop out because $F(t)$ and $e^{-tK}f(\boldsymbol{a},0)$ are independent as continuous time processes? The operator $K$ is not dependent on $F$, and so neither is the solution operator $\exp(-tK)$